# How Can I accelerate/Slow down the rotation of a button in CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

I want my planet to accelerate its motion when it is closer to the sun and slow down when it is farther away from the sun.. Please help me! Thank you

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;

rotationAnimation=[CABasicAnimationanimationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * 1/period ];//multiply more to add speed
rotationAnimation.duration = 15;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount =  HUGE_VALF;
[planet.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"orbit"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `CAMediaTimingFunction`. Check out the [pre-defined timing functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Timing_Functions). You can assign one of these to `rotationAnimation.timingFunction`. It sounds like you want `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut`. I am making the assumption that the planet's starting point is far away from the sun. In code, it would look like this:

Swift:

```
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
```

Objective-C:

```
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

Comment: is there away you can help me in how to use it in my code please

Comment: or give an example of it

Comment: what would you recommend me to use if the planets vary in position with respect to the sun.. so "EaseInEaseOut" would not work on all the planets.. and it does not work the other way around.. it should be different according to each planet..

Comment: Then you would have to use `[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:::]` and give it control points based on the planet's location. I've never used that method before, so you will have to read the documentation and use some good ol' fashion trial and error.

Comment: Thanks alot! I appreciate your  help! :)